# nm not list static method from android native code

Tags: android, linux, nm

I have below android native code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <android/log.h>

#define TAG "MyExam"
#define LOGD(msg) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,TAG,msg);

int testOne() {
    LOGD("one");
    return 1;
}

static int testTwo() {
    LOGD("TWO");
    return 2;
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_sample_jniexam_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    LOGD("JNI");
    testOne();
    testTwo();
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

But when try to run nm to list symbols, the static method testTwo() not found!

```
nm -gD --demangle ./app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libjniexam.so |grep test
000081ed T testOne()
```

Which tool should I use to list static method symbols?

*Update*

Thanks for @dimich's comment, after check the debug symbol file, I found below result:

```
$ nm ./app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libjniexam.so |grep test
000081ed T _Z7testOnev
000082e1 t _ZL7testTwov
```

What does the 'T' and 't' mean in this output?

Comment: Static functions aren't visible outside of current compilation unit so symbols aren't exported. This is purpose of `static` keyword for functions in C. You can try to compile with debug info and extract debug symbols from object file.

Comment: @dimich Thanks, yes, the debug symbol has it, but still not figure out what's does the 'T' and 't' mean in nm output.

Comment: Actually static functions are present in object files with "t" (local text symbol) but optimization can remove it if unused or inlined. If you set `__attribute__((noinline))` to a static function it will be present as "t".